# Gulp sass not compiling

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp

I'm trying to create a simple gulp-sass task and I'm not sure why it's not working. Here's the gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

var scssDir = 'public/assets/scss/';
var cssDir = 'public/assets/css/';

gulp.task('sass-home', function() {
    gulp.src(scssDir + 'blog.scss')
        .pipe(sass({errLogToConsole: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(cssDir));
});
```

And when I run `gulp sass-home`, the task runs and I get the output:

```
[gulp] Using gulpfile /dev/fractal/gulpfile.js
[gulp] Starting 'sass-home'...
[gulp] Finished 'sass-home' after 4.14 ms
```

I don't get any errors logged to the console, but the file is not compiled. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I just tested your code and it works fine for me!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to `cd` in the dir of the sass files and try to execute SASS manually using the flag `--trace` to see if you sass installation works fine

```
sass --trace --watch input.scss:output.css
```

Comment: Thanks for that - I did what you recommended and have found the error inside one of the tributary scss files.

Comment: Was that the problem? If yes, consider checking this as the correct answer.